# Attach Backbone.Marionette Layout to the "body"

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a marionette layout, which I want to attach directly to the  element of the page.

```
App.Views.Layouts.Unauthenticated = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend
  template: "layouts/unauthenticated"
  regions:
   content: "#content"
   header: "#header"
   footer: "#footer"  
  views: {}

 initialize:->
  @el = $("body")
  @delegateEvents()
```

then later in the app, I do this

```
App.layouts.unauthenticated = new App.Views.Layouts.Unauthenticated()
App.layouts.unauthenticated.render()
```

The layout is not attached to the page.
How do I attach it to the body, while I already used body as an "el", since I don't need extra wrappers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `el` in the definition of the view, not in the initializer.

```
App.Views.Layouts.Unauthenticated = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend
  el: "body"
  template: "layouts/unauthenticated"
  regions: ...
```